# Print attribute in the block in a tabular form in autocad

Tags: c#, autocad

This is my code which return me attribute values in the selected block,
but I want these values in a table to show on the dwg file. And the text        must be single mtext object.

```
[CommandMethod("NLTAB")]
  public void ListAttributes()
  {
    Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Editor ed = acDoc.Editor;
    Database db = acDoc.Database;

    using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {

        try
        {

            TypedValue[] filList = new TypedValue[2] { new    TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Start, "INSERT"), new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.HasSubentities, 1) };
            SelectionFilter filter = new SelectionFilter(filList);
            PromptSelectionOptions opts = new PromptSelectionOptions();
            opts.MessageForAdding = "Select block references: ";
            PromptSelectionResult res = ed.GetSelection(opts, filter);
            // Do nothing if selection is unsuccessful
            if (res.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                return;

            SelectionSet selSet = res.Value;
          ObjectId[] idArray = selSet.GetObjectIds();

            PromptPointResult ppr;
            PromptPointOptions ppo = new PromptPointOptions("");
            ppo.Message = "\n Select the place for print output:";
            //get the coordinates from user
            ppr = ed.GetPoint(ppo);
            if (ppr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                return;
            Point3d startPoint = ppr.Value.TransformBy(ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem);
            Vector3d disp = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);
            TextStyleTable ts = (TextStyleTable)tr.GetObject(db.TextStyleTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
            ObjectId mtStyleid = db.Textstyle;
            if (ts.Has("NAL-TEXT"))
            {
                mtStyleid = ts["NAL-FORMAT"];
            }

            var curSpace = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
            MText _outputHeading = new MText();

            _outputHeading.Location = startPoint;
            _outputHeading.Width = 75.207;
            _outputHeading.Height = 1.488;

            _outputHeading.TextStyleId = mtStyleid;
            string file = acDoc.Name;
            string str1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            //string str1 = ("534-W10A-R1");
            //var curSpace = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

            Match match = Regex.Match(str1, @"^(\w+-[CSDWM]\d+[A-Z]-.)$");
            var pattern = @"^(\d+)-[A-Z](\d+)([A-Z])-";

            var groups = Regex.Match(str1, pattern).Groups;
            var _projectCode = groups[1].Value;
            var _phaseCode = _projectCode + "-" + groups[2].Value;
            var _zoneCode = _phaseCode + groups[3].Value;

            curSpace.AppendEntity(_outputHeading);
            tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(_outputHeading, true);
            db.TransactionManager.QueueForGraphicsFlush();

            startPoint += disp;
            HashSet<string> attValues = new HashSet<string>();

            foreach (ObjectId blkId in idArray)
            {
                BlockReference blkRef = (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(blkId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(blkRef.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForWrite);


                AttributeCollection attCol = blkRef.AttributeCollection;
                foreach (ObjectId attId in attCol)
                {
                    AttributeReference attRef = (AttributeReference)tr.GetObject(attId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    string str = (attRef.TextString);
                    string tag = attRef.Tag;

                    if (attValues.Contains(str))
                        continue;
                    if (btr.Name == "NAL-TAG crs ref")
                    {
                        var curSpace1 = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                        MText mtext = new MText();

                        mtext.Location = startPoint;


                        mtext.Contents = tag.ToString() + " : " + str + "\n";

                        //ed.WriteMessage(text);
                        curSpace.AppendEntity(mtext);
                        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(mtext, true);
                        db.TransactionManager.QueueForGraphicsFlush();

                        attValues.Add(str);

                        startPoint += disp;
                    }
                }
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
        catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
        {
            ed.WriteMessage(("Exception: " + ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want the text to appear on the .DWG like a table, but you want them as MText (not as a Table)?

Comment: My first priority is for table if its in text its ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To crate a table, at [this blog post](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/06/creating_an_aut.html), you'll find a sample code in C# that should work for you. The result should look like the image below.

[image]

And here is the source code. After creating the table, if you really need the texts, you can call .Explode() on it and extract all the text entities.

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Geometry;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime;

namespace TableCreation
{
  public class Commands
  {
    [CommandMethod("CRT")]
    static public void CreateTable()
    {
      Document doc =
        Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
      Database db = doc.Database;
      Editor ed = doc.Editor;

      PromptPointResult pr =
        ed.GetPoint("\nEnter table insertion point: ");
      if (pr.Status == PromptStatus.OK)
      {
        Table tb = new Table();
        tb.TableStyle = db.Tablestyle;
        tb.NumRows = 5;
        tb.NumColumns = 3;
        tb.SetRowHeight(3);
        tb.SetColumnWidth(15);
        tb.Position = pr.Value;

        // Create a 2-dimensional array
        // of our table contents
        string[,] str = new string[5, 3];
        str[0, 0] = "Part No.";
        str[0, 1] = "Name ";
        str[0, 2] = "Material ";
        str[1, 0] = "1876-1";
        str[1, 1] = "Flange";
        str[1, 2] = "Perspex";
        str[2, 0] = "0985-4";
        str[2, 1] = "Bolt";
        str[2, 2] = "Steel";
        str[3, 0] = "3476-K";
        str[3, 1] = "Tile";
        str[3, 2] = "Ceramic";
        str[4, 0] = "8734-3";
        str[4, 1] = "Kean";
        str[4, 2] = "Mostly water";

        // Use a nested loop to add and format each cell
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
          {
            tb.SetTextHeight(i, j, 1);
            tb.SetTextString(i, j, str[i, j]);
            tb.SetAlignment(i, j, CellAlignment.MiddleCenter);
          }
        }
        tb.GenerateLayout();

        Transaction tr =
          doc.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
        using (tr)
        {
          BlockTable bt =
            (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(
              doc.Database.BlockTableId,
              OpenMode.ForRead
            );
          BlockTableRecord btr =
            (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(
              bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace],
              OpenMode.ForWrite
            );
          btr.AppendEntity(tb);
          tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(tb, true);
          tr.Commit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but the data in the table is depend on the dwg file which is vary according to diagram.

Comment: this code is an example of how to create a table, you'll need to place the text you want on the rows & columns

Comment: Actually main problem is there i dont know how to take the rows and columns.